# Css File not loading properly in laravel

Tags: css, background-color

This is the inspect css file of the button whose background color is not changing. I changed it in the original file but after inspecting it shows the same

```
 select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

this is my original file:

```
.select2-selection__choice {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:default;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:0 5px
    }
```

But why it keep loading that background color !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the styles in the original file that means - css is changed but browser can't render that. It renders the old cache files.

**Possible solution:** Refresh the cache of your browser and in my 90% case problem had solved.

**Other possibilities of not showing css styles:**

Sometimes we need to override any style and we write and link that. Here, link need to be in last.

That means- we have `select2.css` and `main.css`
in select2 there is something like

```
.test{
   padding: 10px;
}
```

And we want to override that in our `main.css` like,

```
.test{
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Then we've to follow the order of styles linkings. Like first add `select2.css` and then add `main.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

We also do that by adding `!important` of that style

```
.test{
   padding: 10px!important;
}
```

Thus `main.css`'s `test class` can't override the `select2` 's `test class`.

Hopefully you've cleared now about this..